# Facebook Conversation API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

I'm accessing the conversations through conversation API.

The necessary permissions for the API are pages_manage_metadata, pages_read_engagement, and pages_messaging. And the access token is valid too.
But the response is :
{
"error": {
"message": "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.",
"type": "OAuthException",
"is_transient": true,
"code": 2,
"fbtrace_id": "AFwSdNV79mniwQdhyHQ68uA"
}
}

It is working fine for me earlier but when I submitted the APP for verification, it got rejected and the API does not work. I have tried the same API with different accounts pages and created new APPs but the result is the same.

What should be the solution in this regard?